# sort an object in an array which has string key

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this array of objects, I need to sort the 'list' by 'score' in descending order by score.

```
var list =[{ '440684023463804938': { score: 6, bonuscount: 2 },
  '533932209300832266': { score: 20, bonuscount: 0 },
  '448746017987231756': { score: 9, bonuscount: 0 },
  '492585498561216513': { score: 14, bonuscount: 0 } }]
```

I usually do with .sort function, but this time it gives me list.sort is not a function

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if  that's really how `list` is declared, it would definitely have a `.sort()` method. It doesn't much matter because there's only one item in the array, so it's already sorted.

Comment: If you're trying to do `list[0].sort(...)` well that won't work; there's no `.sort()` method on objects because you can't impose your own ordering on object property names.

Comment: That's not an array of objects it's an array of one object!

Comment: oh! sorry..I will edit that question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting JavaScript Object by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value)

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the object to an array and then apply a regular sorting:

```js
const list = [
    {
        '440684023463804938': {score: 6, bonuscount: 2},
        '533932209300832266': {score: 20, bonuscount: 0},
        '448746017987231756': {score: 9, bonuscount: 0},
        '492585498561216513': {score: 14, bonuscount: 0}
    }
];

const result = Object.entries(list[0]).sort((a, b) => b[1].score - a[1].score);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve you JSON architecture, starting with your input:

```js
const input = [{ '440684023463804938': { score: 6, bonuscount: 2 },
  '533932209300832266': { score: 20, bonuscount: 0 },
  '448746017987231756': { score: 9, bonuscount: 0 },
  '492585498561216513': { score: 14, bonuscount: 0 } }];
  

const output = Object.keys(input[0]).sort((a,b) => b-a)
      .reduce( (acc , curr) => { 
                acc[curr] = input[0][curr];
                return acc; 
                },
                {});

console.log([output]);
```